# Text to array conversion

Tags: string, matlab

How do you convert a text file which has commas into an array delimited by those commas? For example, I use

```
var = importdata(filename)
disp(var)
```

This obviously displays the contents which are 
`'please, help, me'`

How do I then get `var` to be an array such that I could extract a single word using something similar to `var(2)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`strsplit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) (requires  ≥ R2013a) or [`split`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/split.html) (requires  ≥ R2016b) to split the character array `var{1}` into a cell array that contains those words at its separate cells.

```
v = strsplit(var{1},', ');   %or v = split(var{1},' ,');
```

Now `v{1}`, `v{2}` and `v{3}` give `'please'`, `'help'` and `'me'` respectively.
`var{1}` is used since you must be returned a cell array `var` from [`importdata`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html). If `var` was not a cell array but a character array then you would not be getting single quotes in the output of [`disp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html).